# How to prove there exists a positive integer $a$ with non-zero digits such that $5^{100}|a$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that: there exists a positive integer $$a=\overline{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}},\qquad a_{i}\in\{1,\dots,9\}$$
>   such that
>   $$5^{100}|a$$

I used [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E%7B100%7D) and I have $$5^{100}=7888609051120118054\cdots$$

This problem is from this PDF(problem 31) :http://wenku.baidu.com/view/de6f0f365a8102d276a22f0a.html

and $5^{100}$ contains zero, so how to prove it? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Start from the right-hand end.  Whenever you find a zero, add a multiple of $5^{100}2^k$, and that shifts the first zero further to the left.  Eventually, you can add a multiple of $5^{100}2^{100}$, then it is easy to remove all the zeros.